# Disable Arcfour encryption

Tags: centos, ssh, encryption

I'm new to this but have been searching everywhere for a clear answer.

To pass PCI compliance the Arcfour cipher should be disabled.

I've tried to edit the ciphers in my sshd_conf and ssh_conf files to no avail.

As far as I can make out the default ciphers are

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

I've tired removing the arcfour instances from that line and also adding a '-' (minus) before them which didn't work either.

How does one disable arcfour ciphers?

We're running CentOS 6.8 in case that helps.

Comment: is it possible that the scanner is finding a separate SSL service that's using arcfour (https)?

Comment: This is the scan command they are using `nmap -Pn -sV --script ssh2-enum-algos 87.xxx.xxx.160 -p22` which I'm assuming is scanning port 22. Would I edit those settings elsewhere?

Comment: you can check what ciphers sshd will allow with; `$ sshd -T 2>/dev/null | grep -i cipher`

Answer (score 7):

CentOS 5, 6 & 7 don't have a Ciphers line in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file so you get the full default list of ciphers. So to exclude arcfour add the following lines to your sshd_config file:

```
# restrict ciphers to exclude arcfour
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

Then restart sshd:

service sshd restart

As noted above you can test using

```
ssh <hostname> -c arcfour
```

If the specified cipher is disabled you'll get a response like

```
no matching cipher found: client arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

otherwise you'll see the normal login process.

Comment: The OP already said that he *has* edited sshd_config, which in case *does* have Ciphers line without any reference to arcfour. But then again it looks like the problem is that sshd doesn't seem to obey his config changes. Nice try, but you realise you ended up replicating what was already posted?

Comment: Sure - not claiming originality. See this more as confirmation that the advice really should work and summarizing in a recipe.

Answer (score 1):

On Centos, RHEL, Oracle Linux 5, 6, and 7, just execute the following as root from a bash shell:

```
echo "Ciphers $(ssh -Q cipher | grep -v arcfour | while read r; do echo -n "$r," ; done)" >>/etc/ssh/sshd_config && /sbin/service sshd restart
```

Comment: ssh -Q works only in version 7 os the said OS.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1

Remove the ciphers "arcfour128", "arcfour256" and "arcfour" from your sshd config.

#### Step 2

Restart sshd: `service sshd restart`

Related read: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jan. I've got this line in my sshd_conf `Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc` i.e. arcfour removed, I've restarted sshd and NMAP is still reporting that those encryptions are still active. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then either nmap is wrong or your sshd uses another config file. Are you 100% sure you edited the SERVER config file (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) and not the global client config? Did you restart?

Comment: I'm 100% sure I've edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Trustwave are using NMAP as evidence that Arcfour ciphers are supported so, ideally I need to get this to work. Thanks again for your thoughts.

Comment: Log on to the machine in question and check yourself: `ssh localhost -c arcfour`. You should get `no matching cipher found: client arcfour server whatever-ciphers-are-enabled-on-the-server`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. I'm logged on. If I type `ssh localhost -c arcfour` it asks me for the password, which I enter and it just takes me back to where I was `[root@s1xxxxx90 ~]#` with a blinking cursor... If I type only `ssh -c arcfour` I get a usage list.